# Horizontal bar or progress bar like feature inside a table

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

Can anyone think of a way to have a horizontal bar chart / progress bar inside a spesific cell inside a table ( IE Row 0, colum 2).

[image: http://i44.tinypic.com/i595pu.png]

So in effect  the text 8,088,874 would have a background coloring showing  the percentage in a visual way.

My setup is atm ASP.NET
Tables are powered by datatables.net

Comment: Do you use some control like `Repeater` or `ListView` for generating table's HTML?

Comment: No its done via datatables.net

Comment: If you are using HTML5 by chance, you should look into the `meter` tag. Support for it is very, very low right now but it's worth learning about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a div the height you want it. Set its background colour to the colour you want it, say red. Set the width to a fraction of what it would be if it were 100% eg:

```
<div style="background-color:red;height:20px;width:100px"></div> 100%
<div style="background-color:red;height:20px;width:75px"></div> 75%
<div style="background-color:red;height:20px;width:50px"></div> 50%
<div style="background-color:red;height:20px;width:25px"></div> 25%
<div style="background-color:red;height:20px;width:1px"></div> 1%
```

Obviously any common css can be moved into a style sheet & you can tweak away to have it fit your layout.

Comment: A solution so simple im assamed i did not think of it myself. Thanks

Comment: Remember you'll perhaps want 2 divs one for each share in contrasting colours. Put your text in the biggest of the two in the opposite colour from that of the div.

Comment: I only stumbled over this looking for a similar solution myself. As you say., so simple.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with JQuery, but I believe there is a progress bar function that will perform this quite easily for you.  Can this not be used within a datatables.net table?

If you are allowed to include simple html in these tables, you could try something like this (copied from my own code with modification) within your cell:

```
 <div id="processingProgBar" style="width:200px; height:14px; position:relative;">
    <img src="imgs/dot_blue.png" id="processingDotBlue" style="position:absolute; height:14px; width:25px; top:0px; left:0px; border:0px; z-index:1;">
    <img src="imgs/dot_black.png" id="processingDotBlack" style="position:absolute; height:14px; width:175px; top:0px; left:25px; border:0px; z-index:2;">
    <div style="color:##ffffff; position:absolute; height:14px; width:200px; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:4; text-align:center;">
        <span id="processingProgBarT" class="normal" style="color:##ffffff;">5</span> / 40 Images Processed
    </div>
 </div>
```

This sets up a static progress bar that can be modified by JS.  Each time progress is made, you would update the innerHTML of the "processingProgBarT" element, then update the width of the "processingDotBlue" element, then update the width and left of the "processingDotBlack" element.  You would do that with script like this:

```
 parent.document.getElementById('processingProgBarT').innerHTML = '6';
 parent.document.getElementById('processingDotBlue').style.width = '30px';
 parent.document.getElementById('processingDotBlack').style.width = '170px';
 parent.document.getElementById('processingDotBlack').style.left = '30px';
```

That particular code would update the progress bar for a sixth image being processed in my example.

You could easily write this into a function, but I had no need to.  Your application appears to require multiple of these on a page, but for that you can just tack a unique identifier (ie: "Row1", "Row2", etc) on the end of each ID then account for that in your function.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily build a progress bar with just html. You might need to use absolute positioning depending on the look you want.

The examples on my blog are for SharePoint, but they can give you an idea of what can be done:

http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/?s=progress

For more advanced customizations, you might also be interested in the jQuery sparklines plugin:

http://www.omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/

**Edit**: I should have mentioned that I use progressive enhancement to achieve the result: a script reads the content of the table and converts it into a chart. This should work with DataTables.
Also, here are two more specific links to my blog:

http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2009/11/02/visualization-calculated-color-gradients/

http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2009/11/25/sparklines-more-information-in-less-space/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use JQuery (or a plugin) you can always do it cheesy by calculating the percentage manually and then drawing a DIV setting the width = % of the table cell based on your calculations.

Are you wanting something ASP.NET related instead of javascript?